# How to search in new files and print the added information?

Tags: ruby

I'm having a problem in my ruby code. My project is to:
Make a new file and put the data inside and than search:
1. Enter a new employee (number, name, date of birth).
2. Search for an employee by number. (in the database) 
3. To exit press 3

This is the code I have, but the terminal won't run it.

```
class Person

    def setNumber(number)
        @number=number
    end

    def setInfo(name)
        @name=name
    end

    def getInfo()
    return @name
    end

    def setInf(dateofBirth)
        @dateofBirth=dateofBirth
    end

    def getInf()
    return dateofBirth
    end 

  puts "Companies employees"

  select = 0

  while(select!=3)

    puts "Press 1 to Enter information about new employee"
    puts "Press 2 to Search for employee by number"
    puts "Press 3 to exit"

  select=gets.chomp.to_i


  if(select == 1)
  f=File.new("Repository.txt","a+")

    puts "Please enter employee number:"
        number = gets.chomp.to_s
        f.puts (number)
        person = Person.new
        person.setInfo(number)

    puts "Please enter the employee name:"
        name = gets.chomp.to_s
        f.puts (name) 
        set_name = Person.new

      set_name.setInfo(name)

        puts "Please enter the employees date of birth:"
            dateofBirth = gets.chomp.to_s
            f.puts (dateofBirth)
            dateofBirth = Person.new
          dateofBirth.setInfo(dateofBirth)

      f.close()

    elsif(select==2)
        puts "Which employee number would you like to search for?"
        search = gets.chomp
        f = File.open("Repository.txt","r")
        while !(f.eof?)
             line.include?(search)

            end

            f.close()



          elsif(select > 3)
            puts "Incorrect selection."

          elsif(select == 3)
            puts "Goodbye!"

            end
          end
```

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages you to avoid using upper-case letters in variable and method names. Capitals indicate constants like `ClassName`, `ModuleName` and `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: It's also not necessary to create `setX` type methods when `attr_accessor :x` creates the proper `x=` method that's used instead.

Comment: What do you mean "won't run"? Does it produce an error? This code looks incomplete and syntactically incorrect, plus the indentation isn't aligning things properly. Indentation might seem like a minor concern, but paying careful attention to that can help expose problems early, avoiding a lot of frustrating debugging.

Comment: What do you mean "won't run it"?

Answer (score 0):

This looks incredibly similar to someone else who asked a similar question yesterday. Maybe a school project going around.

You might check the code here: [I trying to make a code that gives the user a personal number after they have made an user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777799/i-trying-to-make-a-code-that-gives-the-user-a-personal-number-after-they-have-ma/46780789#46780789)