# My ruby program will print all the lines that have a specific key and i only need one

Tags: ruby

So, what am i trying to do is to prevent the code from allowing more entries with the same value in the file. And my guess was that all i have to do is to make a while loop which will ask the user for a new value until it won't be an already existing one. Well... it doesn't work like that it seems. Because...

```
class Person



def initialize
    @person = Array.new 
    check_register
    next_reg = @registration.max + 1
end

def check_register
    @lines   = IO.readlines("database.txt") 
    @fullName = []
    @registration   = @lines.collect do | line |
        idxn = line.index(', Number')
        idxd = line.index(', Date')
        @registration << line[idxn + 10...idxd].to_i
        line[0...idxn]
    end
end 

    def fullName
        puts "\nPlease enter a name."
        name = gets.chomp
        @person.push(name)
    end

    def registration
    puts "\nPlease enter a registration number."
    registration_number= gets.chomp

    if @check_register.include?(registration_number) 
    then
        puts_underlined 'This name is already stored. Returning you to the main menu.'
    end
    @person.push(registration_number)
end

    def dateOfBirth
        puts "\nPlease enter the date of birth."
        cpr = gets.chomp
        @person.push(cpr)
    end

    def addToFile
        File.open("database.txt", "a+") do | f |
            f.puts @person.to_s
        end 
    end
end

def newEmployee
  employee = Person.new
  employee.fullName
  employee.registration
  employee.dateOfBirth
  employee.addToFile
end

def listEmployees
    File.open("database.txt", "r") do | f |
        while ! f.eof?
            line = f.gets
            puts line
        end
    end
end
```

The problem i have is here:

```
def registration

            puts "\nPlease enter a registration number."

            registration_number= gets.chomp

                while File.new("database.txt", "r").include? registration_number
                    puts "This registration number aready exists. \nPlease select a different number"
                    registration_number= gets.chomp
                end

            @person.push(registration_number)
end
```

Because it won't work, it will just allow me to enter an already existing number without any problem...

Comment: what is `regnr`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: Honestly, idk how to explain what it is... but it shoult be the thing that saves all the users entries in the Registration category.

I have like 6 classes of coding all my life... i'm still struggling big time.

Comment: can you show an example line of the text file to determine how to parse it?

Comment: ["Hector", "1", "15.08.1990"] This is how i have it in the txt file

Comment: ["Hector", "1", "15.08.1990"]
["George", "2", "02.08.1987"] This 2 lines for example. I am supposed to ask the user to search for one of them based on the registration number (regnr), which is 1/ 2. So, when i press 1 is should only print the first one, but it prints also the second one, because the whole line has 1, even thou is in the date of birth. Idk how to explain this better :/

Comment: You want to match the second value ... so you could do `if line.scan(/\"[^\"]+"/).to_a[1] == y`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add `puts` statements everywhere step by step to see the values returned by parts of expression. Or type them in an IRB session : `File.new("database.txt", "r")` returns a File instance `=> #<File:xxx.txt>`, not the content of the file.

Comment: You must read the file and collect all existing numbers, as in `refresh` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777799/i-trying-to-make-a-code-that-gives-the-user-a-personal-number-after-they-have-ma/46782820#46782820).

Comment: okay, i have tried to make it as shown there, but i still can't make it work. i have edited the code so you can see what i have done...

Answer (score 0):

Running you code as posted :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:17: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 12
t.rb:25: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 21
t.rb:82: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'if' at 63
t.rb:1: warning: assigned but unused variable - f
t.rb:52: warning: assigned but unused variable - guest

Welcome to capgemini & sogeti

Please enter your name 
aaaaa aa

Press 1 to enlist a new employee
Press 2 to search for employees by Registration number
Press 3 to exit
1

Please enter name.
a1 a
t.rb:9: warning: instance variable @person not initialized
t.rb:9:in `FullName': undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  puts
    from t.rb:36:in `new_employee'
    from t.rb:65:in `<main>'
```

Some comments to your code :

- post error-free code, so that we can copy-paste and work on it
- post only the code necessary to answer your question. For example

  `guest = gets.chomp.to_s`

  and

  `def retnr
      return @regnr
  end`

  are unused and not necessary to solve your problem
- run ruby with the -w option and correct all warnings
- take care of alignment and indentation :

  ```
  if line.include? y
  print line
  ...
    puts "goodbye"
      menuNeeded = true
  ```

  should be

  ```
  if line.include? y
      print line
  ...
    puts "goodbye"
    menuNeeded = true
  ```
- keep names starting with a capital letter for class names and constants
- use legible names : registration_number instead of regnr makes it easier
  for a reader (you in 6 months when you have forgotten what you have written,
  or a maintenance programmer) to understand what the code is doing. It's not
  a problem with modern editors : you type `reg` and the auto-completion will
  type the rest for you
- dateOfBirth is the camel-case style used by most languages for method names.
  date_of_birth is the snake-case style used for variables.
  Rubyist will tell you that the naming convention adopted by the community is
  snake-case for method names, but personally I prefer that distinction
- `@person = Array.new` written in the class is a class instance variable. It
  can be used only at the class level. It is not the same variable as the one used by `@person.push(name)` in `def FullName()`, hence the error.

Here is one solution :

```
class Person
    def initialize
        @person = Array.new # you'll often see @person = []
    end

    def fullName
        puts "Please enter a name."
        name = gets.chomp
        @person.push(name)
    end

    def registration
        puts "Please enter a registration number."
        registration_number = gets.chomp
        @person << registration_number

    end

    def dateOfBirth
        puts "Please enter the date of birth."
        cpr = gets.chomp
        @person.push(cpr)
    end

    def addToFile
        File.open("xxx.txt", "a+") do | f |
            f.puts @person.to_s
        end # file is automatically closed at end of block
    end
end

def newEmployee
  employee = Person.new
  employee.fullName
  employee.registration
  employee.dateOfBirth
  employee.addToFile
end

def listEmployees
    File.open("xxx.txt", "r") do | f |
        while ! f.eof?
            line = f.gets
            puts line
        end
    end
end

while true

    puts "\nPress 1 to enlist a new employee"
    puts 'Press 2 to search for employees by registration number'
    puts 'Press 3 to list employees'
    puts "Press 4 to exit"
    choice = gets.chomp.to_i 

    case choice
    when 1
        puts    
        newEmployee
    when 2
        puts 'search employee by registration number'
        registration_number_to_search = gets.chomp
        searched_number_found         = false

        File.foreach("xxx.txt") do | line |
            #puts "line=#{line}"
            # Note that ["Hector", "1", "15.08.1990"], as it appears in the
            # file, is the string representation of an array. It must be converted
            # back to an array before use. There are often many ways to do things
            # in Ruby, using gems or new methods brought by new releases. I have
            # learned Ruby 1.8 and do it simple, step by step.
            string_of_data = line.chomp[1..-2] # remove NL and brackets
            #puts string_of_data.inspect
            array_of_data  = string_of_data.split(',')
            #array_of_data.each{|d| puts "<#{d}>"}
            _name, registration_number, _date_of_birth = array_of_data
=begin
            puts "n=#{_name}  rn=#{registration_number}  db=#{_date_of_birth}"
            puts "rn=<#{registration_number.strip}>"
            puts "rn=#{registration_number.strip.length}"
            puts "rn=#{registration_number.strip[1..-2].length}"
            puts "rn=<#{registration_number.strip[1..-2]}>"
=end
            if registration_number.strip[1..-2] == registration_number_to_search
            then
                searched_number_found = true
                print 'The employee ', registration_number_to_search, ' is registered as ', line
                break # stop reading more lines
            end
        end

        puts "He's not employed here." unless searched_number_found
    when 3
        puts    
        listEmployees
    when 4
        puts 'goodbye'
        break
    else
        puts "wrong choice #{choice}"
    end
end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 

Press 1 to enlist a new employee
Press 2 to search for employees by registration number
Press 3 to list employees
Press 4 to exit
3

["Hector", "1", "15.08.1990"]
["George", "2", "02.08.1987"]
["Henry",  "3", "01.01.2000"]

Press 1 to enlist a new employee
Press 2 to search for employees by registration number
Press 3 to list employees
Press 4 to exit
2
search employee by registration number
2
The employee 2 is registered as ["George", "2", "02.08.1987"]

Press 1 to enlist a new employee
Press 2 to search for employees by registration number
Press 3 to list employees
Press 4 to exit
5
wrong choice 5

Press 1 to enlist a new employee
Press 2 to search for employees by registration number
Press 3 to list employees
Press 4 to exit
4
goodbye
```

Comment: God bless you. This answer is actually better than the ones we get in class. Thank you so much! It works perfectly, and u really helped me understand lots about the mistakes i made and what i was missing.

Comment: sorry, but do you know why my while loop won't work when i try to prevent the user to add a registration number that is already in the list?

Comment: Which "my while loop" ? In the OP (original post) `def Registration()` you accept any number without checking if it already exists. So I don't understand `while loop won't work when i try to prevent ...`. Do you have a new code ? You could post it as Edit.

Comment: It's edited. No, i don't have a new code, is the same that you have made... i have only tried to prevent the user from using the same value for reg number twice. Because i have noticed that today when i was looking again over it so i could understant better the changes that you have made and while i was trying the same code with more options so i may get a bit better at it... it seems it's not that easy.